# Python accessing instance variable dynamically in method

Tags: python, list, variables

I am trying to add a value to a instance list in python but want to access it dynamically from within a method.

I cannot use dictionaries as I am trying to speed up the sorting of separate lists (boxes) rather than one large list.

Can anybody show me the correct way to do the following?

```
class Boxes:

    def __init__(self):
        self.box1 = []
        self.box2 = []
        #....
        self.box10 = []


    def addToBox(self, value):
        box = self.determineBoxToUse(value)
        ## box = 2
        varname = "box", box ## box2
        self.varname.insert(0, value)

    def determineBoxToUse(self, value):
        ## for this example returns 2
        return 2

    def dumpBox(self):
        print self.box2

Boxes = Boxes();
Boxes.addToBox("123.001234")
Boxes.dumpBox()
```

Error: AttributeError: Boxes instance has no attribute 'varname'

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), although many might suggest you should pursue a different solution.

```
def addToBox(self, value):
    box = self.determineBoxToUse(value)
    ## box = 2
    varname = "box{}".format(box) ## box2
    if hasattr(self, varname):
        getattr(self, varname).insert(0,value)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Boxes:

    def __init__(self):
        self.box1 = []
        self.box2 = []
        #....
        self.box10 = []


    def addToBox(self, value):
        box = self.determineBoxToUse(value)
        ## box = 2
        varname = "box{}".format(box) ## box2
        if hasattr(self, varname):
            getattr(self, varname).insert(0,value)

    def determineBoxToUse(self, value):
        ## for this example returns 2
        return 2

    def dumpBox(self):
        print self.box2


>>> Boxes = Boxes()
>>> Boxes.addToBox("123.001234")
>>> Boxes.dumpBox()
['123.001234']
>>>
```

Comment: Great thanks. Interested to know why you think I should pursue a different option? In general I stay away from variable variable names. But this is for a very specific purpose, for which speed of ordering a large list of values is the main goal. I have tried many different ways of approaching the problem. DB, Redis, etc etc.. So far a variable amount of instance lists (boxes / buckets) seems to be the fastest for what I am trying to achieve. But I could be wrong :) That's why I am trying it.

Comment: Oh not that you have to entirely abandon it, but think of possibly using a dictionary rather than dynamic variable names using hasattr and getattr. However would probably need more context to give a better, more substantiated opinion.

Comment: One thing to note.  When you add attributes to a class, you're adding items to a dictionary, whether you know it or not.  Do `test = Boxes()`.  Then `test.addToBox('123.001234')`.  Now you have a `test.box2`, right?  Well: `print(test.__dict__['box2'])` gets  you `['123.001234']`.